# a question about integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X>0$. I want to show that for all $t>0$ 
$$
1_{\left[\frac{2}{t},\infty\right)}(X)<\frac{2}{t}\int_0^t (1-\cos(uX))\, \mathrm du
$$

Comment: You want to show that such inequality holds for all possible values of $X$? Then existence of $A$ and $B$ does not have to deal with it anyway

Comment: @Ilya yes i want to show this inequlity holds for all X,but why existence of A and B does not have to deal with it anyway?

Comment: Because if there is $x$ such that it violates the inequality, then $X$ can take it with probability zero and you will still satisfy the conditions with $A,B$ but will violate the desired inequality. If no $x$ violates the main inequality, then any random variable satisfies it. Is that clear?

Comment: sorry,you are right ,I wrote my question wrong,I edit it

Comment: I would suggest you just to say "let $X\geq 0$", the information about the fact that it is some random variable is totally unnecessary

Comment: @Ilya yes,of course it's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $s=tX$ and computing the integral on the RHS, the goal is to prove that
$$
\mathbf 1_{s\gt2}\lt2-2\frac{\sin(s)}s.
$$
Since $\frac{\sin(s)}s\leqslant1$ for every $s$, it remains to show that, for every $s\gt2$,
$$
\frac{\sin(s)}s\leqslant\frac12.
$$
Since $\sin(s)\leqslant1$ and $s\gt2$, the result follows.

Likewise, for every $a\gt0$, $t\gt0$ and $x\geqslant0$,
$$
\mathbf 1_{x\gt(a+1)/t}\leqslant\frac{a+1}{at}\int_0^t(1-\cos(ux))\mathrm du.
$$

Comment: The hypotheses with $A$ and $B$ are not needed.